# How to add spaces in and restrict records to 300 characters in xslt

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I wrote an xslt to convert xml to CSV. Essentially the xslt creates records to three hundred characters and add spaces till record reaches 300 limit if there is no data. Below is the xslt, and it is serving my purpose. But i had to use a variable Spaces with 300 spaces in it an use that in record.

My question is i am curious to know if there is any other easier way than the approach i took. Below is my xslt, where you can see the variable spaces. Please let me know if i can use any shorter variable instead.

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'&#x20;'"/>
<xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>
<xsl:variable name="spaces" select="'&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;
    &#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;'"/>


<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payments_group">
    <xsl:variable name="Paymentamount" select="number(translate(wd:Payment_Total_Amount,'.',''))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Var_CheckNumber" select="format-number(wd:Check_Number, '0000000000')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Var_Payment" select="format-number($Paymentamount, '0000000000')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat (wd:CF_Account_number_HSBC_Canada, $delimiter, $Var_CheckNumber, $Var_Payment,wd:Payment_Date, $delimiter, wd:Payment_Payee/@wd:Descriptor, $spaces),1,300)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select='$linefeed'/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Payments_group" group-by="wd:CF_Account_number_HSBC_Canada">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Counter" select="format-number(count(current-group()), '0000000000')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Var_TotalSum" select="format-number(sum(current-group()/number(translate(wd:Payment_Total_Amount,'.',''))), '0000000000')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat ('T',wd:CF_Account_number_HSBC_Canada, $delimiter,$delimiter,$delimiter,$delimiter,$delimiter,$Counter,$delimiter,$delimiter,$delimiter,$delimiter, $Var_TotalSum, $spaces),1,300)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select='$linefeed'/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `for-each-group` suggests you use an XSLT 3 or 2 processor so to construct a string of `$n` spaces you can use XPath 3 or 2, e.g. `string-join((1 to $n)!' ')` (can also be expressed in XPath 3.1 as `(1 to $n)!' '=>string-join()`) or `string-join(for $i in 1 to $n return ' ', '')` in XSLT/XPath 2.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a recursive template to add the needed spaces to pad your text output. Since you do not provide a reproducible example (i.e., original XML), consider below example which pads each text value to reach 10 characters in length:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
    <languages type="special purpose">
        <language>xslt</language>
        <language>sql</language>
        <language>css</language>
    </languages>
    <languages type="general purpose">
        <language>python</language>
        <language>java</language>
        <language>c#</language>
    </languages>
</root>
```

**XSLT** *(see comments to adjust according to your actual XSLT)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <!-- REPLACE WITH YOUR HIGHER LEVEL TEMPLATES -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="language">
        <!-- BUILD SPACES CONDITIONAL ON LENGTH OF TEXT -->
        <!-- REPLACE text() YOUR substring(concat (...)) WITHOUT YOUR LONG $spaces) -->
        <xsl:variable name="spaces">
              <xsl:call-template name="repeat">
                <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="string-length(text())"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- PAD TEXT WITH SPACES -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), $spaces)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <!-- RECURSIVE TEMPLATE -->
    <xsl:template name="repeat">
        <xsl:param name="spaces"/>
        <xsl:param name="n"><xsl:value-of select="$spaces"/></xsl:param>

        <!-- REPLACE 10 FOR YOUR 300 -->
        <xsl:if test="$n &lt;= 10">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="repeat">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template> 
            <!-- REPLACE WITH ANY TEXT VALUE TO BE REPEATED -->      
            <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <languages type="special purpose">
        <language>xslt      </language>
        <language>sql       </language>
        <language>css       </language>
    </languages>
    <languages type="general purpose">
        <language>python    </language>
        <language>java      </language>
        <language>c#        </language>
    </languages>
</root>
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRx/2)